# ALM-PC - Can same license file/keys used from 12.20 to 12.55

Tags: loadrunner, alm, hp-performance-center

We have working ALM-PC 12.20 setup. We are planning to move to latest HPE-PC 12.55 version. So, after clean install of 12.55, can same license file/keys will work on new version?

Also, if we removed old setup and installed latest 12.55 version on different VM(s). Is same license will be valid for the new machine? Or we need to get new license from HP?

Comment: Have you tried contacting the vendor?

Comment: Assume the answer is No until you validate with Microfocus support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loadrunner 12.X all have the same license mechanism. You can use Loadrunner's 12.2 license on Loadrunner 12.55.

Comment: If you are upgrading, get your updated keys from Microfocus support.